# Dual boot PCBSD - Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub, pc-bsd

I am using PC-BSD 10.1.2. I ran the command without adding the Windows partition configuration file as result:

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/pcbsd/theme.txt
done
Installing GRUB to ada1
```

Then when I go to the config file, I don't see anything with Windows label, just PC-BSD.
Any ideas?

P.S I've forgot to say that windows has been installed on a separate hdd (ada0)

Comment: You can boot with windows bootloader and chainload grub from there using easybcd.

Comment: Sorry but easybcd it's not free... and I wanna use grub anyway. ;-) It has to work! Thanks